# Rails: On object validation, attributes are nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models: house, tenant, and plumber.  tenant belongs_to house and house has_one tenant.  I want to use a custom EachValidator that requires data from plumber.  To accomplish this, in my tenant model:

```
attr_accessor :plumber_limit
```

In the controller, I have set the `plumber_limit` with:

```
house.tenant.plumber_limit = plumber.value
```

When the tenant validation fires, the `tenant.plumber_limit` value is nil and, consequently, fails.  I've tried adding a public definition for `plumber_limit`.  I've tried adding `attr_accessible :plumber_limit`.  I've tried different notations.  Is this failing because `tenant` is being used in a child context?  If so, how do I get the `plumber_limit` into the `tenant`'s validation?

By request, here's the validation code:

```
class UniquePlumberAssignment < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.property.limit(record.plumber_limit).each |p|
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you explain more elaborately?

Comment: Please add the code of the validation in your question

Comment: @Paritosh, what would you like me to elaborate upon?